# Android SQLite OpenHelper empty DB on Restart App

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am trying to complete an Android App, using SQLiteOpenHelper to Manage the DB. 
(With singleton)

```
private static WindAppDBHelper sInstance;

    public static synchronized WindAppDBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new WindAppDBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
```

I don't understand why the DB is working very well on RunTime, but after close the app and open again, the DB is (at least it looks) empty??
For example I made a test on my Activity (I have only one activity and I use the db inside my Fragments (Tabs))

Before quit, using debug tools I saw that dbHelper.getAllFavourites() has size=2; (I know, it is a very stupid code, but it is only to test, even the onClose is not necessary if everything goes well with DBHelper...)

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    List<Favourite> test = dbHelper.getAllFavourites();
    test.size();
    dbHelper.close();
    test.size();
    super.onStop();
}
```

After that, when I open the App again, inside the same Activity but inside onCreate and test.size=0... why?

```
    dbHelper = WindAppDBHelper.getInstance(this);
    List<Favourite> test = dbHelper.getAllFavourites();
    test.size();
```

EDIT: WindAppDBHelper [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vascofermandes/SKY_Wind_App/master/app/src/main/java/com/sky/vasco/vascowind/WindAppDBHelper.java)!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you dropping the SQL table somewhere?

Comment: Nope.... I already put a breakpoint inside (onUpgrade), it is the only drop inside the DBHelper... Also made a search for delete, and the only method using delete at the moment is never used. thanks @cricket_007

Comment: Are you changing the database version somehow? That will cause onUpgrade to fire.

Comment: no... just like I told you before, I already tested with a breakpoint inside onUpgrade, to test it. (db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FAVOURITES);)  but the breakpoint has never been achieved!

Comment: Can you post the code for WindAppDBHelper? Maybe it is related to the way you prepare a readable or writable reference.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! Its now available one link to WindAppDBHelper.java! I am very upset with this all situation, because I am using the same DBHelper "base file" that I already use in all other projects, and I never had the same problem...